# Dependency graph for functions in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, graph, dependencies

I have a big VB.NET solution which consists of several files, classes and functions. Is there a way to create a graph that shows how all those elements belong together?

I found a solution for Assemblies and also Visual Studio Ultimate should have such an option but this is too expensive for a hobby coder. Are there any free tools available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the tool NDepend, it is not free but yet cheaper than VS Ultimate. Here it is explained how to generate a [method call graph](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph#Call) with NDepend. A 14 days trial full-featured is available for [download](http://www.ndepend.com/download).

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend.*
[image: NDepend Methods Call Graph]